# Change TextView color programmatically

Tags: java, android

I tried this

```
txt.setTextColor(0xA4C639);
```

But then My Textview is invisible ...
I also added one Color in values but I dont know how to use them programmaticly.

I DONT want to use this :

```
  android:textColor="@color/droid_green"
```

I want to make it in my onCreate

Comment: Please check the updates to my answer and let me know if you have any problem. Good Luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**USE**

```
txt.setTextColor(Color.Black);//use any other color
```

**P.S.**
You can make new Color object as well or use `Static` one as above

**Example of making color object.**

```
Color temp = new Color(R,B,G,A);//R,B,G are integer for Red, Blue, Green ranging from 0 to 255 and A is alpha
```

Or you can use **HexCode** as well as following:

```
Color temp = Color.decode("#FFCCEE");//Change to any other hexcode
```

And finally you can use the **temp** which is object of Color as follow:

```
 txt.setTextColor(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer^^ But I tried Color android_gruen = new Color.decode("#A4C639"); But it fails.It is underlined red and says "Color.decode cant be resolved to a type".Whats wrong `?

Comment: There is nothing I suggested as using **new**

Comment: But the I cant create a new Object of Color.It is saying that the cunstructor with three ints are undefined.Example Color temp = new Color(233,49,49);

Answer (score 1):

you could also have used this.

```
txt.setTextColor(0xffA4C639);
```

An Android color is a 32-bit integer value consisting of four eight bit parts, **ARGB**. Here A stands for alpha which is **00** in your case so you find it **invisible**, FF will set alpha to 100 % and will make your text visible. Hope this helps :)